# Remove an item from QList throws error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How to delete an object form Qlist

```
QList<CascadeJobInfo> m_InternJobInfoList;
foreach (CascadeJobInfo jobInfo, m_InternJobInfoList)
{

    m_InternJobInfoList.removeOne(jobInfo);
}
```

it throws error
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qlist.h:972: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'CascadeJobInfo' and 'const CascadeJobInfo')
             if (n->t() == t)
                        ^

Comment: Once you call removeOne, the list does not remain the same as before. Foreach can go out of the range because some elements have been taken away.

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn `foreach` takes a copy of the list, so this code is safe if inefficient.

Comment: :( so is it safe to use iterator instead of foreach

Comment: @Sijith Please state what you want to do, because here you simply wish to clear the whole list, and that's trivial. But I presume that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `operator==` for type `CascadeJobInfo`:

```
class CascadeJobInfo
{
public:
    <...>
    bool operator==(const CascadeJobInfo & other) const;
    <...>
};

bool CascadeJobInfo::operator==(const CascadeJobInfo & other) const
{
    if (this == &other) {
        return true;
    }

    bool equal = <...compare each data member within this object with its counterpart in other...>;
    return equal;
}
```

The [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#removeOne) says that pretty clear:

> This function requires the value type to have an implementation of
>   operator==().

Also, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve from your code snippet. Attempting to remove each list's item while iterating over the list has a simpler alternative: method [clear()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#clear).

Comment: I want to remove the current item "jobInfo"
Dont want to remove the entire Item

Answer (score 2):

You're not asking how to delete "*an*" object from a list, but how to remove **all** objects. Use `clear()`:

```
m_InternJobInfoList.clear();
```

If you're asking how to remove only objects for which some predicate is true, you'd want to use `erase` instead:

```
auto & list = m_InternJobInfoList;
auto const pred = [](const CascadeJobInfo &){ return true; };
list.erase(std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(), pred), list.end());
```

Of course `pred` could do something more useful.

In the [future C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if) and Qt, hopefully you will be able to simply do

```
erase_if(list, pred);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation but code looks complex, I want to delete particular object "jobInfo" if one parameter in jobinfo matches my member varable

Comment: I am not understanding the code you gave, how u deleted the particular object form list

Comment: @Sijith, you may need to be familiar with the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). If you are, this answer should be clear...